# how to write a loop for search array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I want to learn how to make this code cleaner. I am using JavaScript.

Here is an Array of Objects:

```
var arr = [
    { key: 'qqqqq', value: '11' },
    { key: 'aaaaa', value: '121' },
    { key: 'bbbbb', value: '131' },
    { key: 'ccccc', value: '141' },
]

var obj = { key: 'cccc', value: '-fd-' };
```

My target is to find if obj in arr(it means, arritem.key == obj.key), if it does, update the value, otherwise append the obj to arr.

The idea of a directly is:

```
let has = false;
for(const item of arr) {
    if(item.key == obj.key) {
        item.value = obj.value;
        has = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!has) {
    arr.push(l);
}
```

It's there a cleaner way to achieve ?

Comment: is the key unique?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're restricted to using that given format for the array, you can achieve what you want by turning it into an object or key/value pair...

```
var data = {
    'qqqqq': '11',
    'aaaaa': '121',
    'bbbbb': '131',
    'ccccc': '141'
}
```

then to add or update a value...

```
data['ccccc'] = '-fd-';  // updates ccccc
data['eeeee'] = 'new';   // adds eeeee
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for getting the object or if not found push `obj` to the array.

```js
var arr = [{ key: 'qqqqq', value: '11' }, { key: 'aaaaa', value: '121' }, { key: 'bbbbb', value: '131' }, { key: 'ccccc', value: '141' }],
    obj = { key: 'cccc', value: '-fd-' };
    temp = arr.find(o => o.key === obj.key);

if (temp) {
    temp.value = obj.value;
} else {
    arr.push(obj);
}

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to first search if item exist in your array, you can use `findIndex` => if item is found just replace the value at the finded index by your new `object` else `push` it into your array.

```js
var arr = [
    { key: 'qqqqq', value: '11' },
    { key: 'aaaaa', value: '121' },
    { key: 'bbbbb', value: '131' },
    { key: 'ccccc', value: '141' },
]

var obj = { key: 'cccc', value: '-fd-' };
var obj2 = { key: 'aaaaa', value: 'newValue' };

function updateOrPush(arr,obj){
  var id = arr.findIndex(e => e.key == obj.key);
  if(id > -1){
    arr[id] = obj;
  }
  else{
    arr.push(obj);
  }
}

updateOrPush(arr,obj);
updateOrPush(arr,obj2);
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code would be simpler

```js
var arr = [
    { key: 'qqqqq', value: '11' },
    { key: 'aaaaa', value: '121' },
    { key: 'bbbbb', value: '131' },
    { key: 'ccccc', value: '141' },
]

var obj = { key: 'cccc', value: '-fd-' };

var objIndex = arr.findIndex(ele => ele.key === obj.key);

objIndex < 0 ? arr.push(obj) : arr[objIndex].value = obj.value;
 
console.log(arr);
```